# How to add text and figures one by after severals time?

Tags: floats, text

When I try to add 2 figures and to add text between them, after compiling the text, I get the results: texts above and the two figures below...

I expected to have first figure and text after and after the text another figure and after the last figure another text.

Why it separate them in shape of two text and after the text two figures ?

***first part:***

```
The output results that shown in \autoref*{capacitors_voltages} help us to bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9 \textwidth]{figures/CAP_voltgs}
    \caption{capacitor waveforms.}
    \label{capacitors_voltages}
\end{figure}


From \autoref*{ACcurrents} we can see aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9 \textwidth]{figures/currents}
    \caption{AC side currents}
    \label{ACcurrents}
\end{figure}
```

***second part:***

So, in this code part it behave exactly as I expected:

The number of SMs usually depends on the application,it is very common of using letter N to indicate the number of SMs in each ARM and 2N to whole phase.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figures/Three_MMC_Phase2}
    \caption{General one and three phase of modular multilevel converter (a) and (b) respectively}
    \label{figures/Three_MMC_Phase2}
\end{figure}


The fundamental construction of SM composed from capacitor, IGBTs (S1,S2) and their corresponding free-wheel diodes.\\ 
The two most common SM configurations found in literature are the Half-Bridge (HB) and Full-Bridge (FB) SM, as illustrated in \autoref*{figures/HB_FB}. 
The FB-SM version of the MMC has twice as much semiconductor devices than the HB version, which results in higher losses, but confers certain advantages as well \cite{6864817}, \cite{6631955}. 

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figures/HB_FB}
    \caption{Converter configuration submodules: (a) half-bridge and (b) full-bridge}
    \label{figures/HB_FB}
\end{figure}
```

For the present analysis, and throughout the Thesis in general, the MMC under study is considered to be based on HB-SMs.
Considering submodule structure , is a simple half bridge with a capacitor bank, as shown in `\autoref*{figures/HB_FB}`. Each phase leg of the converter has 2 ARMs, each one constituted by a number of series connected submodules.

So what wrong with the first part ?

Comment: Try with `[!htb]`.  But don't forget figures are floats, and LaTeX places them where it judges best.

Comment: With your code sniped I can't reproduce your problem. Anyway, consider Bernard comment.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just "glued" them together with the text. I had the same problem for a proof and an image I had to add with caption and ended up doing just this:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Image}
\end{center}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

      {\footnotesize text}             {\footnotesize text (for second line)) Text}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Image2}
\end{center}

      {\footnotesize text2}                {\footnotesize text2 (for second line) Text2}
```

Comment: Don't forget \captionof{figure}{...} from the caption or captionof packages.

Comment: Nope I am not using \captionof{figure} I eliminated that and just used \includegraphics[]{} works much better for me, and then below you make your own caption with simple text by changing it's position and his size. Unfortunately I discovered it that caption is a bit of a pain to work with and you don't have as much freedom as free text. That's why I was suggesting it